# Problems with css fixed header not displaying dropdown menu properly

Tags: css

I'm probably doing something wrong here. Here's my code for it:

```css
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000066;
    z-index: 1;
    }
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    }
  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
  li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .droptn {
    background-color: #ccb3ff;
    color: black;
    }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ccb3ff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
    }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block, flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 3;
    }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: white; color: #000066;}
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#quote">Request a Quote</a></li>
  <li><a href="#colors">Colors</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#addressblocks">Address Blocks</a>
    <a href="#balls">Balls and Finials</a>
    <a href="#columns">Columns</a>
    <a href="#coping">Coping (Wall Caps)</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom Products</a>
    <a href="#fireplaces">Fireplaces</a>
    <a href="#edgers">Lawn Edgers and Tree Rings</a>
    <a href="#panels">Panel System</a>
    <a href="#patiostones">Patio Stones and Pavers</a>
    <a href="#parkingbumpers">Parking Bumpers</a>
    <a href="#pierandtiercaps">Pier (Pillar) and Tier Caps</a>
    <a href="#quoins">Quoins</a>
    <a href="#sillsandlintels">Sills and Lintels</a>
    <a href="#splashblocks">Splash Blocks</a>
    <a href="#surrounds">Window and Door Trim (Surrounds)</a>
    <a href="#wainscots">Wainscots</a>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

When my dropdown displays, it appears in the header with a tiny scrollbar, and it doesn't drop down out of the header. I know I'm probably an idiot, and this is likely a super easy fix. [A picture of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaGai.png) I've obviously tried messing with the z-indexes of the elements. It didn't do anything. I've googled my little fingers off, and I've been trying things out. Nothing is working. I'm a dummy, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the overflow is set to auto, thus causing the scroll bar to appear when hovering over the dropdown and being larger than the allocated space. To resolve this, remove `overflow:auto` from header and ul.

See this fiddle for the working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/tdz018ug/